# Validating browser upload file name and extension with simple regex

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, file-upload, cross-browser

I got the regexp right. Works perfectly for Firefox ONLY. How would i make this cross browser, cross platform manner. Since it is file name and extension validation you are right i am using File Upload control.

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_\.]{3,28}(.pdf|.txt|.doc|.docx|.png|.gif|.jpeg|.jpg|.zip|.rar)$
```

matches File name must not be empty[ 3, 28 characters long].

Extension must be within the group.

When this works superb in forefox i assume because the fileUpload.value = Filename.extension in firefox. It awfully fails in Google chrome and IE. I am using the above with .net Regular Expression validator and ClientScript enabled.

**I know how to validate it on server, so please no server side solutions.**

**note:**

Google chrome:

Provides the fileupload control value as c:\fakePath\filename.extension

IE:

Provides the Full path.

Comment: please provide some examples of inputs you try to match and where exactly it fails

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use the `^` to start with if you sometimes have a full path but are only interested in the filename. The dot of the filending should be escaped.

You could try something like this:

```
[^\\/]{3,}\.(pdf|txt|doc|docx|png|gif|jpeg|jpg|zip|rar)$
```

As it looks you get only the file with Firefox but the full path with other browsers.
I'd always add a prefix `/` to your string and than validate the last part after the last fileseprator `/` or `\`.

This example uses lookahead to check the fileseparator (or manually added `/`) before the file and also allows the check of max 28 char for filename. see this [online regex tester](http://www.myregextester.com/?r=a1ebd878):

```
(?<=[\\/])[\w\.]{3,28}\.(?:pdf|txt|doc|docx|png|gif|jpeg|jpg|zip|rar)$
```

Comment: thanks for the valuable explanation. this regex works across browsers now.

Answer (score 1):

As things stand, your regex validates garbage like the following:

- `....pdf`
- `____pdf`

It also rejects perfectly valid files:

- `i.jpg`
- `my-pic.jpg`
- `pic.JPG`

The easiest is to validate things in multiple steps:

1. Extract the extension:

   ```
   \.[a-zA-Z]{3,4}$
   ```
2. Lowercase the extension and validate it against an array of acceptable values.
3. Optionally validate the file's name (though I'd recommend cleaning it instead):

   ```
   [a-zA-Z0-9_-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)*
   ```